# fading out all elements, then fading in selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

What I'd like to do is have a list of links that will match up with a DIV box.  I would like for only one div to show at a time, and have all others be hidden, EXCEPT for the menu of links.

I understand how to write the code to fade out a div, then fade in a new one, but I don't know how to write it so it's 'universal' between all the links.

Does this make sense?

When you first enter the page, there will be a 'splash' page (id="splash").  The menu will be floating and there will be 4-6 links.  When you click on link '1' it will fade out the splash page, fade in page 'one'.  When you click link '4', it will fade out page 'one' and fade in page 'four'.

Can someone help me write it so all I have to do is assign a class to the link and it's appropriate div?  I'm a flippin newb...

Comment: It would make more sense with some sample markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't styled this but I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CjpJB/14/) is what you want.  You could also load the pages via ajax but I simply made one page with different views.

The markup:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Splash</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="splash">
        Splash
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">
        Page 1
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">
        Page 2
    </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
#container > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And the script

```
$(function() {
    var divs = $("#container > div");
    var links = $("#menu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pageToShow = divs.eq(links.index(this));
        if(!pageToShow.is(":hidden")) {
            return;
        }
        divs.not(':hidden').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            pageToShow.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to fadein the page AFTER the fade out is complete so they don't mesh together during the fading process? Also, could I wanted to be able to change the position of the menu after any link is clicked, but only have the change happen ONCE, on the first click.  yay? nay?  So far this is very helpful though. thank you

Comment: I have updated the script/example for the fade effect you wanted.  As for the position, you just need to do some basic javascript using a boolean.  So you have a variable called 'hasBeenClicked = false' and then when the link is clicked you set that to true.  You have an if-statement in the function that checks for this value.

Comment: Thank you!  That should hopefully be putting me in the right direction to figure it out.  I've successfully been able to move the menu and have it fade in/fadeout when any link is click, but it's making it stop doing that after it's been clicked once, for the first time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An example with a splash and three pages;

```
<div class="page" id="splash">
   splash content
</div>
<div class="page" id="page1" style="display: none;">
   page 1 content
</div>
<div class="page" id="page2" style="display: none;">
   page 2 content
</div>
<div class="page" id="page3" style="display: none;">
   page 3 content
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="switchPage(1); return false;">Page 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="switchPage(2); return false;">Page 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="switchPage(3); return false;">Page 3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function switchPage(x) {
   jQuery(".page").fadeOut(600, function() { jQuery("#page" + x).fadeIn(600); }
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you getting a javascript error? check the javascript console.